# Azure Maps: How to install version 3 of the azure-maps-control package

Tags: npm, azure-maps

I tried to install the new version `3.x` [azure-maps-control](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-maps-control/v/3.0.1?activeTab=readme) npm package but it seems to have some problems with Typescript:

1. It refers to an `azuremaps-maplibre-gl` module which cannot be found anywhere. Normal `maplibre-gl` exists but I suppose that the Azure Maps team made some changes to the vanilla version. This dependency seems to be introduced in version `3.0.0-preview.9`.

Errors in `azure-maps-control/typings/index.d.ts`:

2. line 674:23 -  error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'options'. (also defined on line 671:23)
3. line 674:23 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'options' must be of type 'boolean', but here has type 'PitchControlOptions'.
4. line 2135:51 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ElevationTileSource'.
5. line 4097:49 - error TS1246: An interface property cannot have an initializer.
6. line 4101:44 - error TS1246: An interface property cannot have an initializer.
7. line 4105:70 - error TS1246: An interface property cannot have an initializer.
8. line 4109:24 - error TS1246: An interface property cannot have an initializer.

Is this an oversight by the Azure Maps team? Or do I use the package wrong?

**EDIT for people reading this in the future: Package versions starting from `3.0.2` are fixed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known bug in the current NPM package release. The Azure Maps team is looking into this. There is a thread tracking this here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/issues/116